# Media list view with href won't redirect

Tags: html, html-framework-7

I'm creating a hybrid app for iOS and Android and I'm using framework7 to create it. The thing is I have a media list view that `onclick` should redirect to a `page.html`, and it doesn't. I've triple-checked every-name to see if it was a capital letter thing but every name was written correctly. This is the media list view code:

```
<li>
  <a href="Page.html" class="item-link item-content">
    <div class="item-media"><img src="abc.png" width="44"></div>
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-title-row">
        <div class="item-title">Hey!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-subtitle">Hi</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Does someone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 uses ajax pages by default, so your target page should be formatted for this, or you can add the class name `external` to the href tag to open directly.

```
<li>
  <a href="Page.html" class="item-link item-content external">
    <div class="item-media"><img src="abc.png" width="44"></div>
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-title-row">
        <div class="item-title">Hey!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-subtitle">Hi</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Check the documentation note: http://framework7.io/docs/pages-ajax.html